# laravel get last bid from each post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables, Items and Bids.

Items hasMany(Bid);

Table items

- id-1
- id-2
- id-3

Table bids

- id-1 | 3
- id-1 | 4
- id-2 | 2
- id-2 | 5
- id-3 | 4
- id-3 | 6

and now I want to show the highest bid of each item.

and here is my code

```
 $data = PostItem::with([
     'bids' => function($query) {
         $query->orderBy('new_bid','desc')->get();
     }
 ])
 ->get();
```

But the problem is it will takes all bids.

But if I use this code

```
 $data = PostItem::with([
     'bids' => function($query) {
          $query->orderBy('new_bid','desc')->take(1);
     }
 ])
 ->get();
```

It will takes only 1 latest bid, do not take the latest bid of each item.

How to do it properly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add `limit()` to the relation:

```
public function highestBids()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Bid')->orderBy('new_bid', 'desc')->limit(1);
}
```

And then get the highest bids:

```
$data = PostItem::with('highestBids')->get();
```

Comment: the results is same with my second query

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query as:

```
 $items = PostItem::with(['bids' => function($query){
                    $query->orderBy('new_bid','desc');
                }])
                ->get();
```

And now to get highest bids of each item:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $highest_bid = $item->bids->first(); // highest bids of $item
    if($highest_bid) {
       $new_bid = $item->new_bid;
    }
}
```

Comment: this query is right, i can get the highest bid but it results whole array, and if write $item->bids->first()->new_bid it will error

Comment: ya, but the result is same

Comment: By looking at the `$items` dd(), it's sure that `$item->bids` is a collection and `$item->bids->first()` will written an object of `Bid` Model. There might be some other issue but not with the above code.

Comment: i think so, actually i've made similiar thing before but when i copy and pasted the code the result is same. do you think i have problem with my model?

Comment: Keep in mind that this will get whole `bids` table which will kill the request in the real world app. So, use it only if this table will always be small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()` method to get unique records. Try the query below.

```
$items = PostItem::with(['bids' => function($query){
             $query->distinct()
                ->select('item_id')
                ->orderBy('new_bid','desc')
                ->groupBy('item_id')
                ->get();
         }])
         ->get();
```

Comment: this will results only one item, but i want to show all item with its bids. So i think there is something missing with my "bids" query

Comment: i tried with distinct before with it makes 
"Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression"

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer but it may not the best answer.

So i still with my first query and then in the view i am using @foreach.
because I already sort the highest bid first, so i added @break to break foreach so it doesn't loop all result.

but I am sure there is better way to do this